# How to create a PostgreSQL procedure in spring boot using @Query annotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I want to create a PL/pgSQL procedure using spring JPA's @Query annotation. I have tried the following (`kotlin` code)

```kotlin
    @Query("""
        CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE some_procedure(...
        ...
    """, nativeQuery = true)
    fun createDataInsertProcedure()
```

I also tried the `@Modifying` annotation

```kotlin
    @Modifying
    @Query("""
        CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE some_procedure(...
        ...
    """, nativeQuery = true)
    fun createDataInsertProcedure()
```

I also tried using `clearAutomatically`

```kotlin
    @Modifying( clearAutomatically = true)
    @Query("""
        CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE some_procedure(...
        ...
    """, nativeQuery = true)
    fun createDataInsertProcedure()
```

But non of them worked

I have created the procedure directly in the database and it was created successfully.

I don't want to create the procedure directly in the database, I want to do everything through my spring boot back-end. is that alright? or do I need to modify the database directly sometimes?

if there is an easier way (than @Query annotation) to create a PL/pgSQL procedure, please feel free to suggest it.

Comment: "But non of them worked". How did they fail? Stacktrace?

Answer (score 1):

I would do this with an initialization script. You can read the documentation for Springs facility for that here [data-initialization](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization).

Comment: I checked that and that is not what I am looking for. I just want to execute a query that doesn't return a result and the only thing it does is executing a native PL/pgSQL query that creates a PL/pgSQL procedure (or function). it is as simple as that, why is it that complicated to do such a basic thing!

Comment: Stored procedures ordinarily are created once and executed many times. Can you explain why having the stored proc created at startup time doesn't meet your needs? Is there some reason you have to repeatedly create it?